# Not able to manage Product Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-products

[image: AS YOU CAN SEE NOT ABLE TO MANAGE CATEGORIES AS WELL AS THE SUB CATEGORIES ARE NOT SHOWING UP]

AS YOU CAN SEE NOT ABLE TO MANAGE CATEGORIES AS WELL AS THE SUB CATEGORIES ARE NOT SHOWING UP

Comment: Did you check any jquery error in console?

Comment: Can you help me out on how to check that?

Comment: Sure, just check console error and past in your question.

Comment: Can you pass on your mail id

Comment: please check you mail and revert back, thanks